# Present Keynote without showing editor

Tags: keynote

The scenario is that I have a computer whose screen is being projected and visible to an audience. Is it possible to start a Keynote presentation without showing the editor (and thus all the text on the first slide) to the audience? I know Microsoft Powerpoint lets you export a presentation so that opening it immediately starts the presentation. Can Keynote do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Document inspector and enable Automatically play upon open.

[image]

Comment: That works but it still flashes up the editor before playing the presentation, which is a bit annoying.